# "Know to speak" vs. "Know how to speak"

Tags: american-english

I **know to speak** English.
I **know how to speak** English.

What is the difference between the sentences above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know how to speak English.

means that I have the knowledge and capability of speaking English.

> I know to speak English.

means that I am aware that I should speak English. For example:

> Don't speak another language or they will know we are foreign.
>
> Don't worry, I know to speak English.

Comment: I wonder what level of question is appropriate on ELL?